# Wireless headphones (radio or bluetooth) for watching films that don't give headaches

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, headphones, headset

I'm EMF concerned but still need wireless headphones to watch films on my projector without bothering neighbors.

They need to be powerful, robust, highly user friendly and not give EMF-related headache/cancer.

Comment: What is your budget?

Comment: Most types of electromagnetic radiation cannot cause cancer. Those that do are almost never used in communication equipment.

Comment: Your headphones are likely too tight. There's also non radio based wireless tech - say infra red. The technology is fairly mature, tho it would work line of sight only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried these personally - and as with *any* headphones, its a good idea to try any headphones for fit (tight headphones cause headaches) and sound quality if possible, but it sounds like considering your fear of EMF, you might want to consider a IR based unit. IR's basically the same technology used in remote controls, is line of sight, and its technology that's been in common use since the 70s.

Based off the models the [wirecutter](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-wireless-home-theater-headphones/) tried (and sadly, they didn't do a proper review on this, other than saying they weren't really into IR) and the reviews for the model on the [amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009A6CZ26) the Sony MDR-IF245RK might be a model.

Most folks report that its comfortable, but you may need to check the cables you need. Since its IR, if you pick up a second unit, you can use the second headset with the same transmitter (which is handy for movies).

And while I'm personally skeptical of EMF 'sensitivity', I don't think anyone's ever complained of IR sensitivity yet.

Comment: Terrific! Too bad I can't get the Power Acoustik ones delivered here in the UK, but I'll definitely go for IF. Thanks!